# How can I clean up sleeping mysql processes?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, timeout

I have an issue with a rails 4 application that leaves idle mysql connections.  While we look at the code to determine the cause, I at least want to be able to automatically eliminate the offending processes.  The mysql documentation says setting wait_timeout and interactive_timeout will close inactive connections so I've set them both to 300.  However, as can be seen below, there are various processes that exceed the 300 limit.  I've confirmed that the settings are indeed 300. Why isn't mysql eliminating these processes?

```
mysql> show processlist;
+-----+--------------+-----------+--------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id  | User         | Host      | db           | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+-----+--------------+-----------+--------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 143 | application | localhost | application | Sleep   | 1500 |       | NULL             |
| 144 | application | localhost | application | Sleep   | 1499 |       | NULL             |
| 145 | application | localhost | application | Sleep   |    0 |       | NULL             |
| 146 | application | localhost | application | Sleep   |  780 |       | NULL             |
| 147 | application | localhost | application | Sleep   |  783 |       | NULL             |
| 148 | application | localhost | application | Sleep   |    0 |       | NULL             |
| 149 | application | localhost | application | Sleep   |    7 |       | NULL             |
| 150 | application | localhost | application | Sleep   |    3 |       | NULL             |
| 151 | application | localhost | application | Sleep   |    8 |       | NULL             |
| 152 | application | localhost | application | Sleep   |    3 |       | NULL             |
| 155 | root         | localhost | NULL         | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist |
+-----+--------------+-----------+--------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please check your RoR connection pool. It's possible these processes represent MySQL connections being held open by that pool.

Comment: You can activate the general log and check its content to see if there is anything being received from each connection.

Answer (score 0):

try run mysql query  `kill 143;`

this works for me